# 500 ошибка при входе в админ панель Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Сделала полную копию сайта что б развернуть его локально в файле wp-config.php внесла изменения поменяла url сайта и домашней страницы на локальный. Сайт полностью запустился локально, все страницы и переходы работают. Но когда в адресной строке ввожу //site.com/wp-admin/ в место входа в админ панель появляется сообщение о 500 ошибке is currently unable to handle this request. Изменяла название папки с плагинами, делала востонавление  файла .htaccess - это ничего не изменило. Подскажите пожалуйста может есть еще варианты решения данной ошибки?

Comment: Наиболее правильный вариант - правильно перенести сайт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Я по php мало что помню, но вроде бы ошибка 500 может возникать из-за отсутствия поддержки php или неправильной версии php.

Comment: больше нету 500й ошибки но в админ панель я так и  не попала теперь ошибка 404

Comment: @SlavaNikitina вы когда перенесёте сайт правильно, тогда приходите. Пока писать бессмысленно.